# How to animate a ball along the curved path using css3 animation?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have this scenario to animate a ball along a curved path. I don't have any idea to implement this using the `css3`. I know there is no `path` animation kind of stuff.

Is there a way to animate a ball on a curved background.

here is [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x0fbffx9/)

my code :

```css
div.path {
  background:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/images/path.png) no-repeat center bottom;
  width:397px;
  height:66px;
  position: relative;
}

div.ball {
  background : green;
  width:20px; height:20px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="path">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this can help http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/03/03/animating-circular-paths-using-css3-transitions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete solution to your Question, but you asked for how can I define a `path` in css animation, so this is how you can:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x0fbffx9/1/)

```
div.ball {
    background : green;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    border-radius:50%;

   -webkit-animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari 5 */ 
   animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+,IE 10+, safari 5 */
}

@keyframes path {
    0% { transform: translateX(10px)  }
    10%   { transform:  translateX(0px)   translateY(20px)}
     20%   { transform:  translateX(20px)   translateY(40px)}
      30%   { transform:  translateX(50px)   translateY(52px)}
     40%   { transform:  translateX(150px)   translateY(50px)}
}
```

If you see at the code you are actually defining the path for the ball to move as X,Y

Comment: I am finding difficult to match with my bg image. is there any work-around?

Comment: if you are trying to move an object you must know the path on which it should move!